# NgAnimate on page load hack

Tags: javascript, angularjs

With update 1.4.1, AngularJs Animate does not trigger on page loads like it used to. My old solution was similar [to this - plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aoyRehXQnItGYA0EzTOC?p=preview) (found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5130) and worked up to v1.3.9).

```
<script>
  angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('contr', function ($scope, $rootElement) {
    $rootElement.data("$$ngAnimateState").running = false;
  });
</script>
<style>
  h1.ng-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 10s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 10s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 10s ease;
    transition: opacity 10s ease;
  }

  h1.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="contr">
<h1 ng-if="true">Big headline</h1>
</body>
```

But this doesn't work anymore. So instead I'm doing [this - plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZznmGjT3Fqt2BcjX0Imb?p=preview)

```
<script>
  angular
  .module('app', ['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('contr', function ($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.bool1 = false;

    $interval(function () {
        $scope.bool1 = true;
    }, 1, 1); 
  });
</script>
<!--same css and html-->
```

This feels way to hack-ish to me. Is there any better way of causing an animation on page load in version 1.4.1+?

Comment: It seems that in 1.4 $rootElement does not define data function