# Unable to call functions of a basic ngAnimate example

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get a basic example working using ngAnimate, I have  created a jsfiddle which contains code from Angular docs [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16840/)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngAnimate']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';

    $scope.items = ['A','B','C'];

}).animation('.slide', [function() {
  return {
    // make note that other events (like addClass/removeClass)
    // have different function input parameters
    enter: function(element, doneFn) {
        console.log('enter');
      // knows that the animation has concluded
    },

    move: function(element, doneFn) {
      console.log('move');
    },

    leave: function(element, doneFn) {
      console.log('leave');
    }
  }
}]);
```

I would expect at least the enter function to be called, what am I missing here?

Comment: Where is the `.slide` element? Is inside the `MyCtrl` controller?

Comment: In the html check the fiddle please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngAnimate` doesn't trigger on initial load. Here's a Github ticket about it: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10536

Your animation does, however, work! If you add the following to your controller:

```
$timeout(function(){ $scope.items.push('D'); }, 1000);
```

You'll see that `'enter'` is logged. ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16844/))

Similarly, if all of your whole Array is being loaded in the timeout, it will log each of the items. It just has to be after Angular's finished app setup.

There were previously some hacks to make the initial load animations work, but those seem [not to work anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31193836/624590).