# ng-repeat staggered animation on page load in Angular 1.4+

Tags: angularjs, animation

In [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119037/angularjs-1-2-ng-repeat-animation-on-page-load), the answer provides a workaround (a dirty hack) to make ng-enter animations work on page load.

But, after upgrading to 1.4, this statement:

```
$rootElement.data("$$ngAnimateState").running = false;
```

does not work anymore.

**Note:** Using `$timeout` is not an option for me, because I've tried but I need to give a big timeout to make it work (more than 1.5 seconds, unacceptable).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can call animation manually with $animateCss service. Please pay attention to animateOnLoad directive:

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);

angular.module('app').controller('categoriesCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.categories = ['12345', '6789', '9876', '54321'];
}]);

angular.module('app').directive('animateOnLoad',['$animateCss', function($animateCss) {
  return {
    'link': function(scope, element) {
      $animateCss(element, {
          'event': 'enter',
           structural: true
      }).start();
    }
  };
}]);
```

```css
.category {
  display:block;
  font-size:20px;
  background:black;
  color:#fff;
  margin:10px;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
}

.category.ng-enter {
  /* standard transition code */
  -webkit-transition: 2s linear all;
  transition: 2s linear all;
  opacity:0;
}

.category.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  /* standard transition styles */
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/angular-animate.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="categoriesCtrl">
<div class="category" ng-repeat="category in categories" animate-on-load>
  {{category}}
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome solution for staggering animations on load! Also works nice with animate.css-animations instead of transitions:
http://plnkr.co/edit/2vJT2PNdjEABxPupxX1K?p=preview

Comment: This only works for me when I navigate to the relevant view from within the app, if I load the view directly the items all animate together. In my view the items are returned from a $http.get.